# Data Sources Window : override a UserControl's default size of 100*100

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

When specifying a custom control for a property in Data Sources Window, dropping that object onto the Window creates a control that is 100*100 in size. (There is no hard-coded size in the control.)

[image]

Tried to match a Label's HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment values as  they seem to be the only ones differing but control size is indifferently 100*100. (unless I manually fix it)

[image]

Code generated by the wizard :

```
<Label Content="Url:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<HyperLinkControl x:Name="urlHyperLinkControl2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="3" Grid.Row="2" Uri="{Binding Url}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
```

Are there other properties that need to be defined in my UserControl for overriding that default size ?

Generated XAML by the wizard :

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1" DataContext="{StaticResource biographyViewSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Site:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="siteTextBlock1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Site}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Label Content="Text:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textTextBlock1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Label Content="Url:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <SharpControls:HyperLinkControl x:Name="urlHyperLinkControl2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="3" Grid.Row="2" Uri="{Binding Url}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
    <Label Content="Attribution:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="attributionTextBlock1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding License.Attribution}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Label Content="Type:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="typeTextBlock1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding License.Type}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Label Content="Url:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <SharpControls:HyperLinkControl x:Name="urlHyperLinkControl3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="3" Grid.Row="5" Uri="{Binding License.Url}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You must be the only single person in the planet who actually uses the Visual Studio designer for WPF development.

Comment: Lol, actually I use Blend but this is quite convenient for creating a basic template :-)

Comment: Post all your UserControl XAML code.

Comment: @Aybe Not really if you consider that after you finish with the designer, you need to spend 2x the time to fix the crappy XAML generated by it.

Comment: @HighCore : true ! (I'm crafting this on Blend right now)

Comment: @Rafal : here it is ...

Comment: @Aybe : I mean UserControl in which you have `Label` and `HyperLinkControl` presented at beginning of your question.

Comment: Okay, I pasted it now.

Answer (score -1):

In your `SharpControls:HyperLinkControl` you have set property `Height=100`. Just remove this property.